# Calculation of integral (Fourier coefficient)

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I need to calculate the integral

$$\int_{a=-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{ins}}{1- \frac{1}{2} \, e^{i(t-s)}}ds$$

which can be interperted as Fourier coefficient.

I didn't succeed to calculate this integral although I tried many attempts. Any suggestions as to how to calculate the integral?

Comment: What is $f(s)$?

Comment: Of course, sorry about that,I will edit

Comment: Integrating ds or dt ??? $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{ins}}{1- \frac{1}{2} \, e^{i(t-s)}}ds$ or $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{ins}}{1- \frac{1}{2} \, e^{i(t-s)}}dt$  ??

Comment: You have also left out what variable you are integrating with respect to - I would guess it is $ds$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the geometric progression, we can write
$$\dfrac{1}{1- \frac{1}{2} \, e^{i(t-s)}} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{2^k} \, e^{ik(t-s)}}.$$
This series is absolutely convergent, so we can integrate it term by term:
$$\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{ins}}{1- \frac{1}{2} \, e^{i(t-s)}}ds = \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{ins} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{{\dfrac{1}{2^k} \, e^{ik(t-s)}}} \ ds = \\
= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{e^{ikt}}{2^k} \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}} e^{i(n-k)s} \, ds =  2 \pi \dfrac{e^{int}}{2^n} = \dfrac{\pi e^{int}}{2^{n-1}},$$
since 
$$\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i(n-k)s} \, ds = \begin{cases}
0, & k \ne n, \\
2\pi, & k=n.
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{[-\pi, \pi]}\frac{e^{ins}}{1-\frac{1}{2}e^{i(t-s)}}ds$$
Let
$$e^{is}=z$$
Then
$$I=\frac{1}{i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z^{n}}{z-\frac{1}{2}e^{it}}dz$$
There is a pole at $z=\frac{1}{2}e^{it}$ inside the contour. The residue is
$$Res\Big{\{}\frac{z^{n}}{z-\frac{1}{2}e^{it}}; \ z=\frac{1}{2}e^{it}\Big{\}}=\lim_{z\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}e^{it}}\Big(z-\frac{1}{2}e^{it}\Big)\frac{z^{n}}{z-\frac{1}{2}e^{it}}=\frac{e^{int}}{2^{n}}$$
Thus
$$I=2\pi{i}\Big(\frac{1}{i}Res\Big{\{}\frac{z^{n}}{z-\frac{1}{2}e^{it}}; \ z=\frac{1}{2}e^{it}\Big{\}}\Big)=\frac{\pi{e^{int}}}{2^{n-1}}$$